# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function dispatch() on null View\Element\AbstractBlock.php on line 652

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2.2

help needed
i am creating a factory in block and get data from model it give result in block but when i return this factory and use this block function in phtml file it give error " Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function dispatch() on null in C:\wamp64\www\hum\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php on line 652 "
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should return following code:

```
return parent::_prepareLayout();
```

So **_prepareLayout** method looks like:

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    // your modification

    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

Comment: no , i find a mistake myself , i used _construct istead of __construct :)

Comment: But you didn't update your question regarding that. Also, you must apply changes according to my answer as well.